# Need Help Creating a 2D Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a 2 Dimensional array in C# and I can't get my rows and columns to line up. I am trying to get my data in six rows and five columns. The Mon to line up with the 12,10,17,22. Then the Tues to line up with the 11,12,17,22. This will continue to sat. Here is an example of the table.

[image: Example of the Table view in the console]

Here is the code I have built so far.

```
class Zumba
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Zumba table = new Zumba();
        int[,] zumValues = table.ZumbaValues;
        string[] zumForm = new string[6] { "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };
        for (int z = 0; z < zumForm.GetLength(0); z++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", zumForm[z]);
            for (int r = 0; r < zumValues.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < zumValues.GetLength(1); c++)
                    Console.Write("\t" + "{1,2,3,4,5,6}" + "\t", zumValues[r, c]);

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private int[,] zumba = new int[6, 4] { { 12, 10, 17, 22 }, 
                                           { 11, 13, 17, 22 }, 
                                           { 12, 10, 22, 22 }, 
                                           { 9, 14, 17, 22 }, 
                                           { 12, 10, 21, 12 }, 
                                           { 12, 10, 5, 10 } };

    public int[,] ZumbaValues
    {
        get
        {
            return zumba;
        }
        set
        {
            zumba = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? The image of the console looks fine.

Comment: Well for one, this line looks all wrong `Console.Write("\t" + "{1,2,3,4,5,6}" + "\t", zumValues[r, c]);`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `2-dimensional array`, yet 3 `for-loop`s. Also `"{1,2,3,4,5,6}"` is not a valid string format.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Zumba table = new Zumba();
    int[,] zumValues = table.ZumbaValues;
    string[] zumForm = new string[6] { "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };

    for (int day = 0; day < zumForm.Length; day++)
    {
        Console.Write(zumForm[day]);

        for (int time = 0; time < zumValues.GetLength(1); time++)
            Console.Write("\t{0}", zumValues[day, time]);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work;

```
Program table = new Program();
            int[,] zumValues = table.ZumbaValues;
            string[] zumForm = new string[6] { "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };
            for (int z = 0; z < zumForm.Length; z++)
            {
                var Nums = "";
                for (var t = 0; t < 4; t++)
                    Nums = Nums + table.zumba[z, t].ToString() + " ";

                Console.Write("{0} {1}", zumForm[z],Nums);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

i see you have 3 loops while you need only 2, one for rows and one for cols. Moreover you don't need {1,2,3,4,5,6}, because you are cycling and you need only one parameter {0}

Here is what i think you need:

```
static public void Main()
{
    Zumba table = new Zumba();
    int[,] zumValues = table.ZumbaValues;
    string[] zumForm = new string[6] { "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };
    for (int z = 0; z < zumForm.GetLength(0); z++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}", zumForm[z]);
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
             Console.Write("\t"+"{0}"+"\t",zumValues[z, c]);
        Console.Write("\n");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that works:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Zumba table = new Zumba();
        int[,] zumValues = table.ZumbaValues;
        string[] zumForm = new string[6] { "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };


        int r = 0;
        while (r < zumValues.GetLength(0))
        {
            //Write the day
            Console.Write("{0}", zumForm[r]);
            //right the zumba values
            for (int c = 0; c < zumValues.GetLength(1); c++)
                Console.Write("\t" + zumValues[r, c] + "\t");   
            //new Line             
            Console.Write("\n");
            r++;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```